# My reputation went down when I passed 200 and got the Association bonus

Tags: bug, reputation

If you do the math on the reputation, I should be well above 184. Has anything like this happened to anyone else, or will this self correct eventually?

[image]

Comment: Sorry but I don't keep track of my reputation number. Even in Stackoverflow.

Comment: It was pretty noticeable getting a notification for 100 points and then noticing its less than it was before

Answer (score 1):

After a good period if time, it looks like the site recalculated reputation and self-corrected.